# proof of connectedness of $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to give a proof of the connectedness of $\Bbb{R}$ (with the standard topology):

For the sake of argument, suppose $\Bbb{R}$ is not connected. Let $U\subset\Bbb{R}$ be open, closed, nonempty, and $U\not=\Bbb{R}$. Pick $a\in U$ and $b\in \Bbb{R}\setminus U$. Assume WLOG $a<b$. Set $A:=U\cap[a,b]$. Note that $A$ is nonempty since $a\in A$ and bounded. Let $s=\sup A\in\Bbb{R}$.

Case 1. $s\in U$. Then $s\not=b$. Also $s\leq b$ since $b$ is an upper bound for $A$. Hence $s<b$. Since $U$ is open, there exist $r>0$ such that $(s,s+r)\subset U$. Also we can choose $r$ small enough such that $(s,s+r)\subset[a,b]$ since $s<b$. Therefore $(s,s+r)\subset A$ which contradicts that $s=\sup A$.

Case 2. $s\in\Bbb{R}\setminus U$. Note that $\Bbb{R}\setminus U$ is open. There exists $r>0$ such that $(s-r,s)\subset\Bbb{R} \setminus U\subset\Bbb{R}\setminus A$.  [Stuck here. I'm wondering if one could argue that $s-r/2$ is an upper bound of $A$.]

Could anyone help me to finish Case 2?

---

[Added] *This is quite a standard exercise in topology and lots of known proofs can be found in textbooks. I'm just curious about if I can redo the proof in a different way.*

Comment: If you are proving this not simply out of curiosity in a different way of proof, why not just show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\varnothing$ are the only sets clopen in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish off case 2, if $s\not \in U $ and if $(s-r,s)\cap U=\phi$  for some $r>0$ then, since  $A\subset [a,s]$ , we infer $A\subset $[a,s-r]. This implies $s-r\geq \sup A =s$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout just using that path-connected implies connected? Then to show $R$ is connected, you observe that for any $a, b \in R$, you have
$$
g_{ab} (t) = (1-t)a + tb
$$
is a continuous path between them, and you're done.

I know this isn't what you asked, but if you're just seeking another proof of connectedness, perhaps a simple one like this might appeal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @John. That would indeed be very fast. I should have added a few words to the question.

Comment: One would need to show that $[0,1]$ is connected in order to use "path-connected implies connected" I think.

Comment: @Jack You're right.

Comment: Good call, @Jack. D'oh! I'm leaving this answer here as a testament to unclear thinking (or perhaps as a warning to others following this question).